# Laravel and ajax TokenMismatchException on delete request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I try to make `delete` request with `ajax`. Problem is that I always get  `TokenMismatchException` even when I add `X-CSRF-TOKEN` to request header. So any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Here's my request

```
$('#confirm-delete').click(function () {
       if(tableRowId !== -1) {
           var obj = {
               "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
               id: tableRowId
           };
           $.ajax({
               headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')},
               url: 'sarasas/destroy',
               method: 'DELETE', // Type of response and matches what we said in the route
               data: obj,
               success: function(response) { // What to do if we succeed
                   location.reload();
               },
               error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // What to do if we fail
                   console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                   console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
               }
           });
           tableRowId = -1;
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

change this :

```
"X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
```

to

```
"_token": $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
```

or if it's not working Add this JavaScript that sets defaults for all ajax request in jQuery. Preferably in a js file that is included across your app:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `meta` tag with name **csrf-token** in view `head` section like,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    .......
```

then add the following code in your `JS` file.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });
```